# Call GraphQL endpoint from within same Express app without making a HTTP call

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I have a standard Express app, and I'm using `apollo-server-express` to add a GraphQL endpoint to it:

```
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: executableSchema
  });

  server.applyMiddleware({ app: expressApp });
```

I then have the rest of my Express app defining standard REST endpoints. I'd like to keep both interfaces up and running (REST + GraphQL), but reduce the duplication of logic between, say, a POST endpoint handler and a Mutation Resolver, seeing as the meat of the logic for these two is very very similar.

Is there a way to receive a Request in Express, re-format it, and somehow...forward it on the the GraphQL endpoint located on the same server, within the same Express app, without making an unnecessary HTTP call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically possible because you can execute requests against a schema directly (see [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql/#graphql)). However, you'd have to manually map your controllers to specific queries and that's unnecessarily complicated. The better option is to extract the common logic into separate modules that are then used by both your GraphQL resolvers and your REST controllers. Keeping your business logic separate from your controllers/resolvers in this way is best practice anyway -- precisely because of scenarios like this.

```
// post-service.js
module.exports = {
  create: (content, author) => {
    // this just calls another function, but in reality you might include any number
    // of additional steps, for example, transforming and validating the inputs
    return Post.create({ content, author })
  }
}

// post-controller.js
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  const post = await PostService.create(req.body.content, req.user)
  return post
}

// resolvers.js
module.exports = {
  Mutation: {
    createPost: (root, args, ctx) => {
      const post = await PostService.create(args.content, ctx.user)
      return post
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out it is possible to implement an Apollo server with express, in which the express endpoint executes a GraphQL query Directly to our schema. Heare is a code example:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  try {
    //Defied here your GraphQL query in my case I am getting all users
    const query = `
    query getUsers {
      users {
        id
        name
      }
    }`
   
    //Implement authentication if needed
    const autentificationData = autentificateRequest(req)
    
    //Use the graphQl function whith your graphQl schema to execute your query
    graphql({ schema: mySchema, source: query, contextValue: { autentificationData } }).then(result => {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error', error.message)
    res.send(error.message)
  }
})
```

Related [github issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1705#issuecomment-631866041)